# Installing Laravel Valet on macOS Heigh Sierra

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-valet

I'm having issues installing Laravel Valet on macOS Heigh Sierra I already did the following steps.

1. `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"` - this worked fine
2. `brew update` - this worked fine
3. `brew install homebrew/php/php71` - this worked fine
4. `composer global require laravel/valet` - this gives me `command not found.`

I know I'm supposed to add it to the path, but this command `composer global require laravel/valet` should work before I add the path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you install `composer` somewhere before executing it? Try executing `brew install composer` after installing PHP

Comment: Yup, I did that last night and got it working I'll accept your answer :)